# Managing PHP Errors

Tags: php, error-handling, fatal-error, parse-error

I have been searching all over the net to try and find a way to catch all errors thrown by PHP (5.3)

I have been reading through the documentation and it looks like `set_error_handler` is what I need but it doesn't get fatal/parse errors. I'm not sure if this is possible...

Here is my source: https://github.com/tarnfeld/PHP-Error-Handler
Feel free to fork/commit if you know better solutions to all of this.

Thanks in advanced!

## Updated!

Using the answers below I finished writing an [error handler](https://github.com/tarnfeld/PHP-Error-Handler/), it takes care of E_ERROR|E_PARSE|E_WARNING|E_NOTICE and will kill the script when it is fatal! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the manual:

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: `E_ERROR`, `E_PARSE`, `E_CORE_ERROR`, `E_CORE_WARNING`, `E_COMPILE_ERROR`, `E_COMPILE_WARNING`, and most of `E_STRICT` raised in the file where `set_error_handler()` is called.

This means Fatals cannot be caught and handled. What you *can* do is setup an additional handler to be run when the script exits, e.g. [`register_shutdown_function`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

In that handler, use [`error_get_last`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) and check if it was a Fatal Error. This will not allow you to continue script execution though. The script will end, but you can do any cleanup or logging (usually fatals will be logged anyway to the error.log) or whatever.

There is a [user-supplied example in the comments below `set_error_handler`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#99193)

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');
function shutDownFunction() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error['type'] == 1) {
        //do your stuff    
    }
}
```

But note that this still will only catch certain additional runtime errors.

Comment: Sweet. Never thought of using shutdown_function for that.

Answer (score 2):

You may keep an eye on `error_log`. In Ubuntu this is located in `/var/log/apache2/error_log`

Answer (score 2):

So called "fatal errors" is perhaps the most annoying bug in php. The best we can do about it is to convince "php group" to recognize this bug as such, by voting for this request http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28331.

As long as this is not fixed, we're doomed to use dirty hacks like shutdown error handlers or autoloads.

Answer (score 0):

No, catching fatal and parse errors is not possible.
Parse errors because they're raised before script is even compiled.
Fatal errors because they're ... fatal (i.e. script cannot continue running after encountering them)

Comment: That's quite annoying. So keeping myself updated of errors on a production site is pretty impossible! How crappy :(

Comment: Your production code should never have parse errors (come on! that's something a decent IDE will help you with). Also, there are ways of avoiding fatal errors (e.g. check if class_exists() before trying to instantiate object of this class)

Comment: Yeah I know, not so much the Parse errors but I don't want the site to just crash if it runs out of memory for example... Outputting some quick text to the user would be a nice option to have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch fatal errors (including parse errors) the the best solution is to set up error_logging in the php.ini file, e.g.

```
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
```