# Catching "Call to a member function foo() on a non-object" errors

Tags: php, fatal-error

Is there a way to catch `Call to a member function foo() on a non-object` in PHP? It does not sound that serious (as far as fatal errors go), but the [shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) does not seem to be called at all (PHP 5.3, Debian).

**Update:**

How to prevent such errors is really not the point. Sure, one should check for null whenever that is an expected possibility, but littering every single object member function reference with error checking code would result in bloated and unreadable code. Hunting down the occassional error based on the logs is fine - the problem is that logs are not very useful for fatal errors. Using a shutdown function would solve that nicely, but I can't get it to work with this specific type of error; which seems strange to me, because it is not an error which would leave the PHP interpreter in a particularly messy state.

Comment: if(method_exists( would beware you of this sort of error

Comment: register_shutdown always worked for me ... see this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438704/managing-php-errors

Comment: Maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php  and http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this does not sound silly - but you should make sure you know what you are working with. Use [instanceof](http://php.net/instanceof) or [is_object](http://php.net/is_object) where you need - or fix the source of the problem - why is that variable not an object in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to just ensure, that it is an object. Using methods/functions you can use type hints

```
public function x (myClass $object) {
  $object->foo();
}
```

else you may use `is_object()`. At the end such a message sounds like there is a bug within you application, that should be fixed before release, or -- if such a situation can occur by design -- verify the type (`is_object()` (see above) or `!is_null($obj)` or something like that) before trying to call something, that does not exist.

Comment: See the update; it is not realistic to always do the checking. Type hints are cool, but not always applicable (e.g. can't hint for `$obj->foo->bar()`).

Comment: It is. In your update you mentioned, that you don't want to test every single object, but you forgot, that you don't need to check variables, that cannot get any non-object value (except it is a bug, where an error is appropriate). If you design all your methods/functions, that they can always return arbitrary stuff, instead of well-defined values (especially objects with well-defined types), it sounds more like a design flaw. In this case the only solution is to validate every variable.